# Customizing R startup with 'config' package

Tags: r, rstudio

I can use '**config**' package without problems in RStudio. But after I add "**library(config)**" in **.First()** function of Rprofile.site like this:

```
.First <- function() {
    library(config)
}
```

I have a problem in starting RStudio. It gives an error message like:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3omZ.jpg)

So, what's the problem? Is this a bug?

Comment: yeah i can replicate the error. just adding `library(config)` in Rprofile.site will cause this error. it __seems__ like the `config` package overwrites the `get` function which is also used when RStudio is started.

Comment: @chinsoon12, I think you are right. Maybe it's better to use `config:get()` than just `get()`. Thank you!

Comment: its something in the `tools:rstudio` environment that is loaded last when RStudio is started but i cant find where `get` is called. check out `parent.env(environment())` when RStudio is started